# How to create a function-based middleware with process_view() in Django?

Tags: python, django, function, class, django-middleware

I'm implementing a new middleware using a standard implementation:

```py
def my_middleware(get_response):
    def middleware(request):
        return get_response(request)
    return middleware
```

I want to get the `view_args`. I can change to a class-based middleware and implement the method

`process_view(request, view_func, view_args, view_kwargs)`

Is there any other way to get these view_args, view_kwargs in my middleware without changing to class-based middleware?

Comment: What do you mean by `view_args` here?

Comment: The parameters that `process_view` receives

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set **`process_view(...)`** as an attribute of  **`middleware(...)`** function as

```
def process_view(request, view_func, view_args, view_kwargs):
    """
    do something
    """


def simple_middleware(get_response):
    # One-time configuration and initialization.

    def middleware(request):
        # Code to be executed for each request before
        # the view (and later middleware) are called.

        response = get_response(request)

        # Code to be executed for each request/response after
        # the view is called.

        return response

    middleware.process_view = process_view

    return middleware
```

Answer (score 0):

*[process_view()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/http/middleware/#process-view) should return `None` or a [HttpResponse](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/request-response/#httpresponse-objects) object otherwise there is error.

The function with `process_view()`:

```py
def process_view(request, view_func, view_args, view_kwargs):
    # Do something

def simple_middleware(get_response):
    # One-time configuration and initialization.

    def middleware(request):
        # Code to be executed for each request before
        # the view (and later middleware) are called.

        response = get_response(request)
        # Code to be executed for each request/response after
        # the view is called.

        return response

    middleware.process_view = process_view # Here

    return middleware
```

The class with `process_view()`:

```py
class SimpleMiddleware:
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response
        # One-time configuration and initialization.

    def __call__(self, request):
        # Code to be executed for each request before
        # the view (and later middleware) are called.

        response = self.get_response(request)

        # Code to be executed for each request/response after
        # the view is called.

        return response

    def process_view(self, request, view_func, view_args, view_kwargs):
        # Do something
```